# How to upload photos(transferred from iPhone) using web-whatsapp in MAC

Tags: macos, photos, heic

I am not sure if this question belongs to this group.

When I take photos using my iPhone then the Photos are usually with `.HEIC` extension. Now from my iPhone I am able to upload the photos to whatsapp. I am guessing that may be iPhone is converting the Photos to JPG/PNG/etc before uploading the Photo to Whatsapp.

Now I have transferred photos from my iPhone to MAC(Please see the Edit below at the end). When I try to upload a Photo using Web-Whatsapp from my MAC then I am not able to upload `.HEIC` files as they are greyed out. I can upload `.HEIC` photos as files/documents in Web Whatsapp but then the photo will be displayed as a downloadable file instead of displaying it within whatsapp chat

What is the solution for this situation? Is there a setting I can use when transferring Photos and Videos from iPhone to MAC, so that I can select to convert .HEIC to .PNG automatically?

> EDIT:
> Earlier, I was importing the photos from iPhone into the `Photos.app` in MAC. This is not the right way, if the intention is to just transfer the Photos from iPhone to the FileExplorer/Finder in MAC. For transferring Photos from iPhone to MAC I need to use `Image Capture.app`. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7090485

> But the question is still valid. Even though I used ImageCapture app to transfer photos from iPhone to MAC, all the Camera photos except screenshots are imported as .HEIC and not .PNG. I am not aware of any setting in iPhone to change the photos automatically to .PNG when transferring to Laptop

Comment: The solution probably is to convert from HEIC to JPG/PNG first on the Mac, and upload the converted picture.

Comment: OTOH how exactly to you transfer your photos from the iPhone to the Mac?

Comment: @nohillside: I imported the Photos from iPhone into the MAC's `photos.app`. Then in Photos.app preferences -> Show in Finder I can see the photos. Not sure if there is a better way to transfer photos from iPhone to MAC without using iCloud

Comment: @firstpostcommenter: If the intention is to just transfer Photo and Video files to FileExplorer/Finder in MAC, then the better way to transfer photos from iPhone to Computer(MAC) is to use ImageCapture.app. Please see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7090485

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297134/how-to-convert-a-heif-heic-image-to-jpeg-in-el-capitan https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374556/force-airdrop-images-to-be-jpeg-not-heic/383485#383485

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a setting on the iPhone to transfer photos in `.PNG` format.

To enable it:

1. Go to *Settings*
2. *Photos*

Select this option:

[image]

I just tested this and all my photos imported in a `.PNG` format.

Comment: I already selected automatic option for Photos app in iPhone. Are you transferring the photos to MAC or Windows? For Windows machine, the photos were transferred as .PNG but in MAC when I imported the Photos from iPhone into the `Photos.app` in MAC then most of the photos are imported as `.HEIC` format. Only screenshots in iPhone got transferred to my MAC as .PNG or .JPEG

Comment: Can you tell the steps that you did to transfer a Photo from iPhone to MAC?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter I tried it using Mac. I went to `Photos.app`, clicked my device under *devices* on the left and then import. Did that not work for you?

Comment: After importing the photos into `Photos.app`, where are the .PNG photos in finder? I see the photos in "Originals" folder but all those photos are in .HEIC format and videos are in .MOV format

Comment: @firstpostcommenter If you have the photos in Photos, just use the Export function to create JPG or PNG